# How to avoid SoapClient PHP to decode base64 response result?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

Am using SoapClient (PHP) to retrieve data from a remote webservice. And I am able to communicate perfectly with this webservice. The request am sending is supposed to retrieve base64 encoded image data.

It turned out that SoapClient automatically decode base64 response and the result looks like this:

```
b"PK\x03\x04-\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00.d!UÉVÆ│        \x00\x14\x00report.pdf\x01\x00\x10\x00g\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00┌\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00ýX{t\x14ı\x19'\x01óØ▓mO╩1Ð\x02╣«F@Ï╠{g\x07ÆÓ¯,ø╔µMêBö╔¯d3╔¯╠23øW\vÕ`j┼\x17\x1EETT¼¿Á\x05Z± ...
```

My question is how prevent this automatic decoding by SoapClient. My REST API need to transfer the base64 string as it is to another service.

Comment: So just encode it again before sending on

Comment: Encode this output just like this to base64 won't resolve the problem.

Comment: @BorisEKUE-HETTAH, can you explain why it won't? Base64 is bidirectional so there shouldn't be a problem going back and forth.

Comment: My bad! @RiggsFolly, Chris-hass you're right. Encoding back to Base64 was the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, I just had to encode back to Base64.